# React hook not setting an objects state with async await. Always undefined

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, setstate

Wrote an UpdateSOR function for a component called updateSOR which can be navigated from a previous page called SOR.

UpdateSOR is a form which should be pre-filled from the api. So if user comes directly to this page or from the previous page, i do make an api call written below in useEffect and set the value of const [SOR] which would be used in the form to pre fill it as soon as the page loads.

```
 export default function UpdateSOR(props) {
    const [SOR, setResult] = React.useState({}); // empty object
    useEffect(() => {
        const getSOR = async () => {
            console.log("Inside async");

            await QueryService.getSOR(props.match.params.sorID).then(
              (result) => {
                console.log("Inside await then");
                if (result.status === 200) {
                  setResult(result.data.data.dataItems); // set the value for SOR here 
                  console.log("result.data.data.dataItems" ,result.data.data.dataItems);
                }
              }
            ).catch(error => {
              console.error(error);
            });
            getSOR();

          }
      }, []);


console.log("Value of SOR" , SOR) // value of sor is empty object which was during initialization and SOR is not coming from the api written above in useEffect :(

 return (

    <Container fluid={true} className="pt-4 pb-4 pl-0 pr-0">
        <Row className={`align-items-center ${classes.header}`}>
            <Col lg="10">
                <h4 className="pl-4">Form SOR</h4>
            </Col>
            <Col lg="1">
                <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleSave} className="mr-3 float-right">
                    Save
                    </Button>
            </Col>
            <Col lg="1">
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleCancel} className="mr-3 float-right">
                    Cancel
                    </Button>
            </Col>
        </Row>
        <form className={`${classes.form} ${classes.body}`} noValidate autoComplete="off">
            <Row>
                <Col lg="2" onChange = {(event) => setSelectedSorName(event.target.value)}>
                    <CommonInput
                        id="sor_name"
                        label="SOR Name"
                        defaultValue={SOR.SOR_NAME}
                        disabled={false}
                        multiline={false}
                        rows="1" />
                </Col>
            </Row>
)
```

When i try to console.log the value of SOR, i dont get the values from api.
Am i doing any error here. One possibility i think is i am not using async await properly. This is my queryService file from where i am calling this api in this updateSOR file

```
function getSOR(id) {
    if(id) {
        return axios.get(`${Constants.API_URL}/SOR?id=${id}`);
    } else {
        return axios.get(`${Constants.API_URL}/SOR`);
    }

}
```

Comment: What does this log return `console.log("result.data.data.dataItems" ,result.data.data.dataItems)`?

Comment: This is the object which we return from the api @BrianThompson. But this do not get called even

Comment: Yes the api gives you json object like this {"data":{"dataItems":[{"SOR_NAME":"COBRA"}]}}

Answer (score 0):

you can't use async await with then catch.

your getSOR is async function and you cant use .then .catch blocks

do this isntead:

```
const[SOR, setSOR] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
       const fetchSOR = async () => {
           try {
               const {data} = await QueryService.getSOR(id);
               setSOR(data);
           } catch(e) {
               // if response is rejected this will execute
               console.log(error);
           }
       }
       fetchSOR();

    }, []);
```